# Using merge_asof() but skipping NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I would like to fill one dataframe, `dfa`, with reference values from another matrix, `dfb`, using `merge_asof()`.

```
dfa
                 time   A   B   C
0 2016-05-25 00:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
1 2016-05-25 01:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2 2016-05-25 02:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
3 2016-05-25 03:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
4 2016-05-25 04:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
5 2016-05-25 05:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
6 2016-05-25 06:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
7 2016-05-25 07:00:00 NaN NaN NaN

dfb
                  time     A   B    C
0  2016-05-24 23:34:00   1.0  31  101
1  2016-05-24 23:55:00   NaN  35   22
2  2016-05-25 01:00:00   3.0  37   24
3  2016-05-25 01:14:00   4.0  42   99
4  2016-05-25 01:30:00   5.0  15   57
5  2016-05-25 02:00:00   6.0  20   30
6  2016-05-25 03:35:00   7.0  66   45
7  2016-05-25 03:45:00   8.0  44   86
8  2016-05-25 03:59:00   9.0  30   76
9  2016-05-25 05:10:00  10.0  12   65
10 2016-05-25 05:13:00  11.0  15   15
11 2016-05-25 05:23:00  12.0  17    9
12 2016-05-25 05:44:00  13.0  10   13
13 2016-05-25 06:00:00  14.0  20   18
14 2016-05-25 06:35:00  15.0  25   23
15 2016-05-25 06:40:00  16.0  24   40
```

Using `merge_asof()`, I get:

```
test_df = pd.merge_asof(dfa, dfb, suffixes=['_x', ''], on='time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1H'))
test_df.drop(list(test_df.filter(regex = '_x')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
test_df
                 time     A     B     C
0 2016-05-25 00:00:00   NaN  35.0  22.0
1 2016-05-25 01:00:00   3.0  37.0  24.0
2 2016-05-25 02:00:00   6.0  20.0  30.0
3 2016-05-25 03:00:00   6.0  20.0  30.0
4 2016-05-25 04:00:00   9.0  30.0  76.0
5 2016-05-25 05:00:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
6 2016-05-25 06:00:00  14.0  20.0  18.0
7 2016-05-25 07:00:00  16.0  24.0  40.0
```

This does exactly as I anticipate it should, **but I would like for `merge_asof()` to skip the NaN found at `2016-05-24 23:55:00` and jump back one more, so that it gets the value `1.0`.** Is there a method of doing this? And furthermore, is there a scale-able approach? In this instance I would only have to fix one element, but what if I needed the same rule, but for thousands of elements inside my resultant DataFrame?

EDIT:

It occurs to me now that I could solve this version of the problem with `pd.DataFrame.fillna()`, and that I didn't formulate my problem statement with a more complex version that I wanted.

If I had the following reference `dfb`,

```
dfb
                  time     A   B    C
0  2016-05-24 23:34:00   1.0  31  101
1  2016-05-24 23:55:00   NaN  35   22
2  2016-05-25 01:00:00   3.0  37   24
3  2016-05-25 01:14:00   4.0  42   99
4  2016-05-25 01:30:00   5.0  15   57
5  2016-05-25 02:00:00   6.0  20   30
6  2016-05-25 03:35:00   7.0  66   45
7  2016-05-25 03:45:00   8.0  44   86
8  2016-05-25 04:00:00   NaN  30   76
8  2016-05-25 04:25:00   NaN  23   74
8  2016-05-25 04:40:00   NaN NaN  NaN
8  2016-05-25 04:59:00   NaN  27  NaN
9  2016-05-25 05:10:00  10.0  12   65
10 2016-05-25 05:13:00  11.0  15   15
11 2016-05-25 05:23:00  12.0  17    9
12 2016-05-25 05:44:00  13.0  10   13
13 2016-05-25 06:00:00  14.0  20   18
14 2016-05-25 06:35:00  15.0  25   23
15 2016-05-25 06:40:00  16.0  24   40
```

My output would end up being:

```
                 time     A     B     C
0 2016-05-25 00:00:00   NaN  35.0  22.0
1 2016-05-25 01:00:00   3.0  37.0  24.0
2 2016-05-25 02:00:00   6.0  20.0  30.0
3 2016-05-25 03:00:00   6.0  20.0  30.0
4 2016-05-25 04:00:00   9.0  30.0  76.0
5 2016-05-25 05:00:00   NaN  27.0   NaN
6 2016-05-25 06:00:00  14.0  20.0  18.0
7 2016-05-25 07:00:00  16.0  24.0  40.0
```

In this case, I want to jump back NaNs, which `pd.DataFrame.fillna()` solves, but I only want to go back at most an hour. So, my ideal output would look something like:

```
                 time     A     B     C
0 2016-05-25 00:00:00   NaN  35.0  22.0
1 2016-05-25 01:00:00   3.0  37.0  24.0
2 2016-05-25 02:00:00   6.0  20.0  30.0
3 2016-05-25 03:00:00   6.0  20.0  30.0
4 2016-05-25 04:00:00   9.0  30.0  76.0
5 2016-05-25 05:00:00   NaN  27.0  74.0
6 2016-05-25 06:00:00  14.0  20.0  18.0
7 2016-05-25 07:00:00  16.0  24.0  40.0
```

In this case, there's parameters like `limit`, but those are fixed to be integers, which in the case of time, would imply that all my time steps are equidistant. From the reference DataFrame this isn't the case, so is there a way of implementing limit with `pd.DataFrame.fillna()`, but based on time? Is the best approach to resample my `dfb` such that it has equidistant spacing and then use `fillna()` with a specified limit?

Comment: I didn't read in details, but can't you simply `ffill` before merging?

Comment: This did actually occur to me, and would solve the original problem statement. It then occurred to me that there was a more complex case, and have updated the question accordingly.